# overloaded operator reading from csv file

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, istream

I have a csv file that has data like so: `03/10/2016 09:10:10 PM, Name, Genre`

and I have loaded operators that read in the date as integers (DD/MM/YY) and time as integers (HH:MM:SS) and the PM as char, Name and Genre as strings. Here's my code:

In my Time class:

```
istream & operator >> (istream & is, Time & time)

{
    char colon;
    is >> time.hour >> colon >> time.minute >> colon >> time.second >> time.PM;

    return is;
}
```

and my Date class

```
    istream & operator >> (istream & is, Date & date)

{
    char slash;
    is >> date.day >> slash >> date.month >> slash >> date.year;
    return is;
}
```

I read in my file in another class like so:

```
string line; //declaration
Show show; //declaration

while (!inFile.eof())
{
    inFile >> date;

    cout << "Date = " << date.getDay() << "/" << date.getMonth() << "/" << date.getYear()<< endl;

    inFile >> time;

    cout << "Time = " << time.getHour() << ":" << time.getMinute() << ":" << time.getSecond() << " " << time.getPM() << " " << endl;


    getline(inFile, line, ',');
    show.setName(line);

    cout << "Name = " << line << endl;

    getline(inFile, line, ',');
    show.setGenre(line);

    cout << "Genre = " << line << endl;

    showVector.push_back(show) //pushback the objects into a vector<Show> showVector
}
```

So basically, as you can see, I printed out what the program reads in to test and there's just a small issue:

```
Date = 16/11/2004
Time = 9:30:20 P 
Name = M
Genre = House, Medical Drama
```

Why is the M in PM being skipped over and assigned to the Name?

Comment: `ostream & operator >>`  -- Is this a typo?  If it is, you should copy and paste your actual code, and not try to type it in from scratch.

Comment: You should show your time class definition, but it looks like you said the PM field is a char.  You can't read 2 characters into that.  Maybe you should make it a string.

Comment: PaulMcKenzie - Yes, sorry. Fixed it.

Comment: Retired Ninja - When I make it a string, the Time = 9:30:20 PM, House, Medical Drama

Comment: @ssskh12 I would recommend using an array instead of a string.

Comment: Post the definition of `Time`. It may have something to do with the type of `Time::PM`.

Comment: @ R Sahu PM is a char, as I've stated above.

Comment: Then simply read the second char into `colon` as you did with the colons...

Comment: Oh, and you might need to read in the next comma, too.

Comment: Off topic: `while (!inFile.eof())` is a common source of errors that you'll stumble across shortly. More here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong

Comment: @Aconcagua oh cool! I did `is >> time.hour >> colon >> time.minute >> colon >> time.second >> time.AMPM >> colon >> colon;` and that solved it. It was a really simple fix. Thanks a ton!

Comment: @user4581301 okay thanks, i'll go for something else then

Comment: I recommend something along the lines of option 2 in Kerrek SB's answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7868936/read-file-line-by-line/7868998#7868998

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is this line, which isn't consuming enough characters:

```
is >> time.hour >> colon >> time.minute >> colon >> time.second >> time.PM;
```

Before running the line, your input stream contains `09:10:10 PM, Name, Genre`.  The fields are then read as follows:

```
"09" >> time.hour (int)
":"  >> colon (char)
"10" >> time.minute (int)
":"  >> colon (char)
"10" >> time.second (int)
"P"  >> time.PM (char)
```

After reading these characters, the remaining stream is `M, Name, Genre`.  The `getline()` call reads from the beginning of this to the next comma, storing the string `"M"` in `Name`.

In order to remove the full string "PM" from the stream, you need to read two characters.  One way to do this is to read and discard one extra character at the end.

```
is >> time.hour >> colon >> time.minute >> colon >> time.second >> time.PM >> colon;
```